# Validação do AngularJS não funciona muito bem

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, bootstrap-3

Tenho um formulário em que é mostrado dentro de um modal, utilizado pelo framework Bootstrap, e por causa disso, a validação do angular não funciona direito. Somente alguns campos são validado e ainda sim de forma aleatória.

Um exemplo, tenho nesse formulário três campos: Nome, Sobrenome & Email.
As vezes o campo email é validado e o nome também, se eu fechar o modal, esse campos não são mais validados. E assim vai.

Alguém teria alguma dica que pudesse resolver isso?

As validações são:
Email tem que ser do tipo email e campo obrigatório
Campos nome e sobrenome tem que ser obrigatório somente.

O código do meu formulário:

```
          <form class="ui form" name="add_usuario">
            <div class=" required field">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" ng-model="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="required field">
                <label>Nome</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="nome" name="nome" required>
            </div>
            <div class="required field">
                <label>Sobrenome</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" required>
            </div>
            <div>
               <button class="ui blue ok button" ng-class="{'loading': enviando}" ng-disabled="add_usuario.$invalid || enviando">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Vale lembrar que essa validação só não funciona quando está dentro do modal, ser colocar ela diretamente na página, esta validação funciona sem nenhum problema.

Comment: edite sua pergunte e coloque os códigos utilizados ou pelo menos o código da validação para vermos o que você esta fazendo de errado. E que tipo de validação você precisa? Campos vazios? Numero de caracteres? Se for campo vazio basta um required no no input e por ai vai, edite a pergunte  e conseguiremos lhe ajudar mais.

Comment: Você pode colocar seu código completo ai, com o HTML scripts e modal? testou em quais Browsers?